# Node.js HTTP-Response into variable

Tags: node.js, http, variables, httprequest, global

I try to get the response of the http-request to my variable "temperature" but it doesnt work, i already tried it with callbacks but im not really familiar with it so i cant solve my problem right now. Maybe someone has an idea?

thanks and best regards :-)

```
var temperature = ''; 


http.get(url, function(res) {

//console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

var bodyarr = [];

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        bodyarr.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
        //console.log(*/bodyarr.join('').toString());
        temperature = bodyarr;  
    });



    enter code here
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});



console.log(temperature);
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about asynchronicity here; the temperature object is undefined at that point since the log method is called before the request is done. Use the [`http.request`](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request) as it's asynchronous; it takes a callback as parameter which you pass to response.end if you want to have the complete response:

```
//The url for example is 'www.random.org/temperatures/?min=1&max=100'
var options = {
  host: 'www.random.org',
  path: '/temperatures/?min=1&max=100'
};
var temperature = ''; 
var http = require('http');
callback = function(res) {
  var bodyarr = [];
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    bodyarr.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log(req.data);
    console.log(bodyarr);
    temperature = bodyarr.join(); 
  });
}
var req = http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: Did you test your code? Where did you defined your temperature variable?

Comment: My apologies I have updated the answer to include the `temperature` object, this is not tested but merely a suggestion based on [working code](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)

Comment: Well, it´s the same result, the output via console.log works, but temperature is empty :-/

Comment: It's empty because you are trying to assign an array `bodyarr` to a string `temperature`. Either join the elements of the array into a string using the `join()` method and then assign it to `temperature` variable OR simply change the `temperature` variable to an array.

Comment: Nope, still the same result :-)